# zookeeper configs for Giraph 1.0 on Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hadoop-yarn, giraph

New to stack exchange and Giraph so please overlook mistakes and ask any clarifying questions.

OS: ubuntu 13.10

Hadoop/Yarn: hadoop-2.2.0/ (2-node cluster)

Giraph: 1.0.0 (EDIT: trunk)

I'm getting a NullPointerException (NPE) when I attempt to run the following example:

> $ hadoop jar
>   $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner
>   org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif
>   org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
>   -vip /user/hduser/rrdata/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op
>   /user/hduser/rrdata/output/tiny_graph.out -w 1

Stack Trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.giraph.yarn.GiraphYarnClient.checkJobLocalZooKeeperSupported(GiraphYarnClient.java:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.giraph.yarn.GiraphYarnClient.run(GiraphYarnClient.java:116)
>     at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:96)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:126)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

It seems zookeeper related. I installed zookeeper but not having used it before it seems like the configs are wrong. I've tried `-Dgiraph.zkList=hostname:port` and related options but get 'Unrecognized option' exception.

Looking for the correct zookeeper settings for this scenarios. I'll post a reply if I figure it out.

Comment: are you sure you're running 1.0 and not trunk?

Comment: Initially, I had downloaded 1.0.0 from 'apache.claz.org/giraph/giraph-1.0.0/'; but switched to github 'github.com/apache/giraph.git'; since sources were missing and hadoop2.0.0 binaries were not packaged. Is that mapped to the trunk? I'm new to github and haven't looked at branching yet.

Comment: I just checked and you're right, I'm on trunk. Does that change anything wrt the problem above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example how you can specify -D flags:

```
hadoop jar giraph-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar    org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -D giraph.zkList="zkNode.net:2081"  org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation  -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/rav/giraph/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/rav/giraph/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

Btw local zookeeper is not supported in Giraph yet (GiraphYarnClient):

```
  /**
  * Check if the job's configuration is for a local run. These can all be
  * removed as we expand the functionality of the "pure YARN" Giraph profile.
  */
  private void checkJobLocalZooKeeperSupported() {
     final boolean isZkExternal = giraphConf.isZookeeperExternal();
     final String checkZkList = giraphConf.getZookeeperList();
     if (!isZkExternal || checkZkList.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Giraph on YARN does not currently" +
            "support Giraph-managed ZK instances: use a standalone ZooKeeper.");
     }
  }
```

Unfortunately checkZkList is NULL so you will never see this exception :)

Comment: Thanx a lot! I had tried a few variations but couldn't find documentation to specify exactly the external zookeeper to giraph.  This problem is resolved but now hitting another exception.

Comment: As an aside, do you know how this can be specified in a config file instead of on the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set this in conf file. What is the other exception you get now?

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/giraph-user/201311.mbox/%3CCAFEw3YhGid3wtGmwbpXRXtfTi89fokX2r2pMPUoJEkmMawF2VA%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: It's because your workers can't connect to Zookeeper server, and that is because you haven't replaced zookeeper hostname and port with your server information! Also - it's pretty clear if you talk a look at container's logs. Use: yarn logs -applicationId <application_id>. Also could you tell me how could I replay to your email on apache mailing list?

Comment: Sorry, I can be a total moron. I've fixed that and re-ran with another error. You should join the mailing list, seems like you are giraph enthusiast and it would be valuable both ways.

Comment: It seems like our cluster needs a particular setup that's missing for giraph to function. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Giraph job requires 2 containers to run; cluster only hosts 15
 at org.apache.giraph.yarn.GiraphYarnClient.checkPerNodeResourcesAvailable(GiraphYarnClient.java:230)

Comment: At the moment when you tried this - are you sure there was enough resources to run Giraph job? It seems to me that Giraph fails to start when there are all resources occupied. Also I have bad news for you - at moment it seems that even though Giraph application succeed to compute results it never finishes, and go into forever loop in org.apache.giraph.utils.ProgressableUtils: waitFor: Waiting for org.apache.giraph.utils.ProgressableUtils$ExecutorServiceWaitable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42150/discussion-between-vishal-and-ravwojdyla)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if people at Giraph actually pay attention to bug reports, I already reported this issue with a patch as [GIRAPH-795](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GIRAPH-795) two weeks ago :(

Comment: Hi Rob, I saw your bug report and was surprised that they opened a new bug for the same issue based on this thread. I was trying to find the right option and now hitting the same exception you reported on the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the NPE is probably the lack of a giraphConf to check for ZK settings. i think this is due to earlier problems in the run. Looks like the examples jar was not supplied using a -yj argument. the jar you run with "hadoop jar" is typically giraph-core itself.

Good luck, please post on the Giraph user list if you have more trouble.

Comment: Yep, ravwojdyla helped out with that. I hit other issues and moved on to other pressing items but will try the suggestions you and others provided on the user list. Currently evaluating Jung but would rather user Giraph due to the scale.